# Azure communication calling - app terminated due to unrecognized selector sent to class - when im reporting to ACS method

Tags: ios, swift, azure-communication-services

im working on the Azure communication calling. application open state i have implemented the callkit for notifying to user that new call is coming. it was working fine. in terminated state im following the microsoft document there they have method called CallClient.reportIncomingCall(with: callNotification, callKitOptions: callKitOptions). calling this method giving below crash please help me to find out this.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[ACSCallClient reportIncomingCall:callKitOptions:withCompletionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1079acc00'

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let dictionaryPayload = payload.dictionaryPayload
    print("dictionaryPayload: \(NSDictionary(dictionary: dictionaryPayload))\n")
    
    if type == .voIP {
        let callNotification = PushNotificationInfo.fromDictionary(payload.dictionaryPayload)
        
        let callKitOptions = CallKitOptions(with: ProviderDelegate.createCXProvideConfiguration())
        
        CallClient.reportIncomingCall(with: callNotification, callKitOptions: callKitOptions) { error in
            if error == nil {
                print("Killed state reportNewIncomingCall was succesful.\n")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

[reference microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/how-tos/calling-sdk/callkit-integration)

[pushRegistry screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mx8r.png)

Answer (score 0):

The underlying code is written in Objective-C. In ObjC methods are called `selector`. Due to Objective-C being a very dynamic language, the compiler does not enforce the existence of the method in this case.

It's quiet literally telling you that the following method doesn't exist:

```objectivec
reportIncomingCall:callKitOptions:withCompletionHandler:
```

Double check you're calling the method with the right named parameters, and instances of the right classes, and check that the instance at `0x1079acc00` is an instance of the class the method belongs to. Look at your stack trace for more clues.

Please link the documentation so we can compare it against how you're calling it.

Comment: Byron thanks for your support it was fixed when i update the pod version before it was '2.4.0' changed to '2.5.0'

use_frameworks!
ACSFrameworkVersion = '2.5.0'
target 'iOSApp' do
  
  pod 'AzureCommunicationCalling', ACSFrameworkVersion
end

Comment: No problem! So it was indeed missing due to framework versions :)